# Swift: Thread 1 signal SIGABRT in class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutlet

I'm following a tutorial and every time I click the button I get an error in AppDelegate.swift that says Thread 1 signal **SIGABRT**.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { //Thread 1 signal SIGABRT
```

Here's a screenshot of my storyboard. 
[image]

I have looked all over and some answers refer to an `IBOutlet` connection that doesn't exist but as you can see in the screenshot all my connections look good so I don't know what the problem is.

**here's my viewController.swift code**:
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = input.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(input, forKey: "myName")
    input.text = " "
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myName") as? String{
      label.text = x
    }
}
```

}

**here's the complete error message that I get when I click the button**:
2017-08-20 23:29:09.155350+0800 asd[2297:997880] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x608000284d30 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc28340be50.height == 20   (active)>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x608000283980 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc28340be50]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fc28340b780 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x608000284dd0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc28340c420.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x608000284d80 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc28340c420.bottom == UIView:0x7fc28340b780.bottom   (active)>",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2017-08-20 23:29:11.137163+0800 asd[2297:997880] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/Myeongjeon/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/200D40A8-EFD4-4FE9-8E13-37C2E7D86BA6/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-08-20 23:29:11.137610+0800 asd[2297:997880] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-08-20 23:29:15.719443+0800 asd[2297:997880] [User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object ; layer = > as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key myName
2017-08-20 23:29:15.723 asd[2297:997880] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object ; layer = > for key myName'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103725b0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010318a141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010378e625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103678729 _CFPrefsValidateValueForKey + 249
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036e5afc -[CFPrefsPlistSource sendMessageSettingValue:forKey:] + 572
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010378fdaa -[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_setValues:forKeys:count:] + 794
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010374cc58 -[CFPrefsSource setValues:forKeys:count:removeValuesForKeys:count:] + 264
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103678620 -[CFPrefsSource setValues:forKeys:count:] + 32
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103786af6 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_setValues:forKeys:count:] + 454
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010374cc58 -[CFPrefsSource setValues:forKeys:count:removeValuesForKeys:count:] + 264
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103678620 -[CFPrefsSource setValues:forKeys:count:] + 32
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036bbfe9 -[CFPrefsSource setValue:forKey:] + 57
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103788a4f __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 319
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010378824d normalizeQuintuplet + 317
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103788909 -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 105
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103772c15 -[_CFXPreferences setValue:forKey:appIdentifier:container:configurationURL:] + 261
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036bbf34 _CFPreferencesSetAppValueWithContainer + 68
    17  Foundation                          0x0000000102c89790 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 55
    18  asd                                 0x0000000102bafc51 *TFC3asd14ViewController6buttonfCSo8UIButtonT* + 1073
    19  asd                                 0x0000000102baff6a *TToFC3asd14ViewController6buttonfCSo8UIButtonT* + 58
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000103b4ad82 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000103ccf5ac -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000103ccf8c7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000103cce802 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000103bb87ea -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000103bb9f00 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000103b66a84 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010434a5d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000104342532 __handleEventQueue + 1122
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036cbc01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036b10cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036b05ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036b0016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107d05a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000103b49134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    35  asd                                 0x0000000102bb1927 main + 55
    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106d9a65d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: You probably have a `@IBOutlet` variable in your view controller, which isn't connected to anything on your storyboard.

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint in the Breakpoint Navigator (⌘7) to get more detailed information.

Comment: @TristanBeaton I only have 3 IBOutlet variables in my view controller and all 3 of them are properly connected as u can see in the screenshot

Comment: You are not showing enough info (your code or output in the debug console), so we need to guess many parts. One hint for guessing is that you get that error every time you click the button. Your connection of `@IBAction` (not `@IBOutlet`) may be broken.

Comment: Can we at least see the code connected to the button press?

Comment: Enable exception breakpoints and post the complete error message from the console window visible in your screenshot.

Comment: I just edited the question and added a screenshot of my code. If you guys can tell me where the problem is I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Why don't you include your code as text?

Comment: Thanks. with showing your code as text, easy to read, easy to search and easy to copy and fix it.

Comment: @OOPer I just changed it to text. I also noticed that the error says there's something wrong with my constraints but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's critically wrong with your code is here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = input.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(input, forKey: "myName")
    input.text = " "
}
```

You are trying to save `input` into the standard `UserDefaults`, but `input` is a `UITextField`. You cannot save `UITextField` into `UserDefaults`.

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = input.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(input.text ?? "", forKey: "myName")
    input.text = " "
}
```

The most important part in your debug output:

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object ; layer = > for key myName'**

It is saying that your code is trying to set an invalid value for the key `myName`.

Messages about constraints suggests your code and storyboard settings may need to be fixed, but it is not the cause of the crash.